# Getting the earliest date when installment is repaid

Tags: mysql

I have a table as such

```
Loan_no | Installment_no | due_amt | due_date    | repayment_amt | repayment_date
1       |       1        |  1000   |  2022-04-28 |    NULL       |    NULL
1       |       2        |  1000   |  2022-05-28 |    1000       |    2022-05-28
1       |       3        |  1000   |  2022-06-28 |    1000       |    2022-06-30
1       |       4        |  1000   |  2022-07-28 |    1000       |    2022-07-28
```

And I would like to get the earliest date where the installment is paid and the installment will be paid in ascending order. For example, although there is no payment for the first instalment, the payment for the second instalment will be used to pay for the first instalment and so on an so forth. so the resulting table should look something like this:

```
Loan_no | Installment_no | due_amt | due_date    | repayment_amt | repayment_date
1       |       1        |  1000   |  2022-04-28 |    NULL       |    2022-05-28
1       |       2        |  1000   |  2022-05-28 |    1000       |    2022-06-30
1       |       3        |  1000   |  2022-06-28 |    1000       |    2022-07-28
1       |       4        |  1000   |  2022-07-28 |    1000       |
```

This is the simplest problem to solve and I understand that there is a function Lead() in mySQL8.0 but there are cases for example where the repayment_amt is less or more than the due amt

Comment: It would be helpful if you included case where over and underpayments occur.

Comment: can you provide a more complex example of input and output?